# Acess boost ptree across multiple threads

Tags: c++, xml, boost, thread-safety, boost-propertytree

I'd like to make a system, that loads options out of an XML-file into a ptree and acess this ptree across multiple threads.
Sofar, i have mad a simple class, that is accessible to every thread, that contains the methods put(id) and get().
Unfortunately, ptree doesn't appear to be threadsafe, so the program crashes a lot.
Is there a way, to make ptree threadsafe? Or is there a better solution all together?

Comment: whay don't you use a mutex in the put, get operations?

Comment: K, ill have a look at it, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *guardian* template structure described int [this blog post](http://www.mr-edd.co.uk/blog/associate_mutexes_to_prevent_races).

Basically, you will create a `guardian<ptree>` instead of a plain `ptree`. A guardian is a opaque structure that holds a `mutex` alongside its data. The only way to access the data is via a `guardian_lock`, that will lock the `mutex`.

```
guardian<ptree> xml;

//thread 1
{
  guardian_lock<ptree> lock(xml);
  lock->put("a", "b");
}

//thread 2
{
  guardian_lock<ptree> lock(xml);
  lock->put("c", "d");
}
```

As you can only access the inner `ptree` through the lock, and the lock locks the mutex, you will never have race conditions.